# If cell has a 1 or 3 in it, radio button selected or not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, I am running into an issue. I have a database, simplified here, but basically If a question is pulled, and an aswer was given in another form, I need to have it so that when the question was pulled from the archive, it would show the answer via a radio button.

The first photo shows it being true, the 2nd is false. Is this possible using straight excel formulas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i understand correctly, you can do this using a form control option button (available on the developer tab of the ribbon). In the control properties you would need to link to a cell formula in another cell that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE depending on if the answer is 1 or 3.

Comment: Insert the option control by choosing Developer > controls > Insert > Option Butoon (Form Control). Right-click the control choose Format Control > Control > Cell Link: E4. Where E4 contains a formula like `=E3=1` assuming E3 is the value of Answer.

Comment: That won't work for what I am attempting...if it's 1 I want Internal highlighted, if it's 3 I don't want internal highlighted, but External Highlighted. Your fomula won't work in this concept. If I enter it into the button exactly, it says refrence not valid.

Comment: @MattRidge if you use option buttons and link to a single cell, then use a vlookup against your question number in that cell it will make the option button reflect checked or unchecked. Unfortunately that is 1 or 2 not 1 or 3. Probably this can be adjusted for in the formula. but not sure what you mean by internal and external. You don't need to enter a formula in the control, but the cell it is linked to

Comment: @datoo The way I have it set up it's 1 or 3, there is a reason for this, so please... don't assume I'm wrong on this. That being said if you look at the images. If you type in 4 where it shows question, the answer will show up as 3. Or in you type on 10 in the question section, the asnwer will be 1. When the 3 is shown, I want the False raido button to be higlighted, when 1 I want True radio button to be highlighted.

Comment: Even if it is 1 or 2 which it's not in my case, how do you change it so that when the option is selected prior you can see the answer via radio button? Sort of like if this was a test, and someone submitted the answer true, and you went back to see what their answer was, you'd see the radio button true pushed.  I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: hopefully I haven't misunderstood what you intended. if you have to show the actual result of 3 then have the vlookup formula hidden elsewhere and link the controls to it. Then do a vlookup without the IF for what is in D2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link the option buttons TRUE & FALSE to in this example D2
and in that cell have this formula =IF(VLOOKUP(D1,$F$3:$G$12,2,FALSE)=3,2,1)
This will change a 3 to a 2 for the representation of the result as a false, and anything else will be 1 or(true).
If you have other values you can adjust the formula for them as well.

One of the problems is that someone changing the selection of true or false will change the formula to that fixed value, so lock the cell.

Hopefully this shows what is meant.
You might even hide D2 so it is not confusing, since the Option Buttons are what you want to have represent your result

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you make it so that if shows in D2, 2, the false is highlighted, and if it's 1m the true is highlighted automatically? Is this possible?

Comment: that is what this does. It makes a 3, into 2, or if it is already 2 linking the both controls to D2 will accomplish that. so if it finds a 3 or 2 it uses 2, which sets the control to false, otherwise it is 1 which is true